# Cors error 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' works on localhost but not on server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

in my spring boot application i have a custom Filter which sets the cors related headers. This works perfectly on localhost, my requests are going through my custom Filter and the headers are filled out.
But when I deploy my application to a server then I get an error, and it seems the preflight request doesn't call my custom Filter.

This is my Filter

```
@Component
public class CustomAllowAllCorsFilter implements Filter {
final private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAllowAllCorsFilter.class);

private boolean allowAllOrigins;

public CustomAllowAllCorsFilter() {
    logger.info("init filter corsssss");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    logger.info("doFilter - allowAllOrigins: " + allowAllOrigins);

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (allowAllOrigins) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, OCTO-Security-Type, OCTO-Security-Name, OCTO-Security-Token, OCTO-Security-Business");
    }

    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS"))
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    else
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Value("${cors.allow-all-origins}")
public void setAllowAllOrigins(boolean allowAllOrigins) {
    this.allowAllOrigins = allowAllOrigins;
}
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Failed to load http://xyz:8080/app/invoices: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xii.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: you have a log statement `logger.info("doFilter - allowAllOrigins: " + allowAllOrigins);` what is that printing on your server?

Comment: Additionally, I recommend creating a list of allowable origins for your different spring profiles instead of just allowing whatever the origin being sent is. Allowing any origin kinda defeats the purpose of CORS protection

Comment: the log statement doesn't print anything, thats the point. The Filter isn't called if I deploy it on the server. At localhost it works perfectly. I know I should doesn't allow any origin but thats another point.

Comment: is your init log printing or is that not either? and is it possible your server has its own CSRF protection built into it, which is rejecting your request before it gets to your java app? Might be able to find that in your servers error logs. If you havent looked there yet, you should check them.

Comment: yes the init log prints out. OK thats a point I will check the Tomcat maybe it handles the CSRF Stuff.

Comment: it was a tomcat problem on the server, I run into several problems to deploy spring boot as war in tomcat so I decided to go the jar way in a docker container.